# Game Boy: Half-carry flag and 16-bit instructions (especially opcode 0xE8)

Tags: assembly, embedded, emulation, cpu-architecture, gameboy

Like so many others, I am writing a Game Boy emulator and I have a couple of questions regarding the instruction 0xE8 (`ADD SP, n` with an 8-bit immediate).

It is claimed [here](http://www.codeslinger.co.uk/pages/projects/gameboy/hardware.html) that in 16-bit instructions the half-carry flag is set if a carry occurs from bit 7 to bit 8, whereas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868396/gbz80-what-constitutes-a-half-carry) it is said that the half-carry flag indicates carry from bit 11 to bit 12. In [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/EmuDev/comments/4ycoix/a_guide_to_the_gameboys_halfcarry_flag/) there seems to be a bit of confusion regarding the issue, and the (notoriously flawed, I hear) [Game Boy CPU manual](http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf) doesn't seem to have anything useful to say either.

My questions are the following:

1. How does the half-carry flag behave in opcode 0xE8?
2. How is the opcode 0xE8 implemented in the physical hardware?
3. Which is right, that half-carry occurs from bit 7 to bit 8 or that half-carry occurs from bit 11 to bit 12 (in the case of 16-bit instructions)?

Comment: While I don't know the answer to this, perhaps [Blargg's CPU test ROM](https://github.com/retrio/gb-test-roms/tree/master/cpu_instrs) could be of use to you. They are pretty thorough.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for commenting. I am aware of said ROM and will happily use it once my emulator is in the required shape (it is not a coincidence that the question has to do with an operation starting with the letter "A" ;)).

Comment: I guess it makes sense to have an 8-bit immediate operand in `ADD SP,n`. Makes the instruction smaller (saves you a byte), faster (saves you a fetch), while sufficient for its typical use case (push/pop a stack frame). Why are you interested in its effect on the half-carry flag? I would expect that flag to be relevant only for `DAA`.

Comment: @RuudHelderman It does make a lot of sense in the hardware, just not in the light of the documentation we have. And yes, as far as I know the half-carry flag is only there for the `DAA` instruction. However, I wish to make my emulator as accurate as possible (within reason, obviously), so I would very much like to implement this instruction the way it actually works in hardware.

Comment: was 0xE8 a custom instruction that was not part of the documented instruction set?  If not what does the documentation say for that instruction?

Comment: @old_timer That depends on what you mean. As far as I can tell, it's not in the Z80 so it would seem to be "custom" in that sense. The Game Boy CPU manual only says that the H and C flags are "set or reset according to operation" and I can't seem to find anything better in any of the other formal pieces of documentation.

Comment: The 7-to-8 claim is not backed by references. The 11-to-12 claims _are_ backed by some very good references, but unfortunately, these all apply to the original Zilog Z-80 implementation. Gameboy's CPU adopted (part of) the same instruction set, but that doesn't guarantee it has the same [4-bit ALU](http://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html). Sharp may well have taken the liberty to wire the half-carry flag in a totally different way, especially when it concerns instructions where half-carry is deemed irrelevant. Only a real Gameboy can tell.

Comment: @ihonen yeah that's what I meant was it added by [I cant remember the chip vendor].

Comment: maybe you have to determine it experimentally.

Comment: @RuudHelderman: DAA might be the only instruction that *reads* the half-carry flag, but lots of instructions can write it.  (Assuming it's anything like x86's AF nibble-carry flag).  Anyway yes, `add reg16, sign_extended_imm8` is obviously good for code density and not weird at all.  Most ISAs with registers wider than 8-bit have immediates narrower than operand-size, and only a few (like x86) have encodings with full-width immediates (like `add eax, imm32` as an option vs. `add r/m32, imm8`).  IMO the question would be better without that sidetrack.

Comment: Typically you don't check the flags after moving the stack pointer. For this reason I even doubt that the behavior of C and H flags after the E8 operation was well specified - which would mean that different versions of the CPU might even set the two flags differently. I doubt that any existing software is using one of these two flags after the E8 operation. So it would not be a problem if your emulator does not emulate the flags of an E8 operation.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I'm aware of that, it's just that this issue bothers me and I'd like to know the technically correct answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes As I pointed out, the instruction is weird in terms of the documentation we have since the semantics regarding the half-carry flag is very non-obvious, not necessarily in terms of having operands of different sizes.

Comment: Yes, that's why I upvoted your question.  You're agreeing with me that the tangent about the 8-bit immediate is unrelated to your question, so I'll remove it for you.

Comment: https://github.com/mamedev/mame/blob/d40fd387d04973e549e14e2398e31aada51f7472/src/devices/cpu/lr35902/opc_main.hxx#L1307

Comment: Just for future reference, this site might be a better fit for these kind of questions: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SM83 CPU core used in Game Boy almost certainly has a 8-bit ALU, which means 16-bit ALU operations are actually composed of two 8-bit operations. Like a normal Z80 CPU, it also has a dedicated 16-bit increment/decrement/load unit, which can handle certain 16-bit operations quickly but can't update the flags. Basically:

- if flags are updated, a 16-bit operation definitely involves the ALU, so it actually uses two 8-bit ALU operations under the hood
- if flags are not updated, and the 16-bit operation is just +1 / -1 / load, it's done with the 16-bit incrementer unit

So, whenever you're dealing with flags, try to think in terms of 8-bit operations (low byte first, then the high byte) if you want to reason about the operation.

> 1. How does the half-carry flag behave in opcode 0xE8?

As pointed out in the other answer, H is set when there's a carry from bit 3. (And C is set when there's a carry from bit 7).

Here's an interesting thought exercise: if `SP=$FFFF` and you execute `ADD SP, -1`, you get `SP=$FFFE` *and both H and C are set*. Can you understand why?

> Due to how signed numbers work, the low byte operation is in this case basically just a normal addition. `-1` = `$FF`, so it's calculating `$FF`+ `$FF`.

Hint above ↑

> 2. How is the opcode 0xE8 implemented in the physical hardware?

We don't yet have a full understanding of it at the lowest possible level, but I know that there are two 8-bit operations. With my Game Boy testbench system I've confirmed that there's first an ALU operation that updates the flags (H, C) but not SP, then some other operation, and finally SP is updated atomically in one go. This suggests that `ADD SP, e` might actually calculate the result into some temporary register (for example, a real Z80 has an invisible WZ temporary register for some ALU operations) in two separate 8-bit operations, and then load SP from it.

I think `ADD HL, BC` is a bit more interesting example...with my testbench I've confirmed that it updates L first and then H, and *flags are updated twice*. This means that it literally executes something like

```
ADD L, C
ADC H, B
```

The latter 8-bit operation updates the flags, so we never see the resulting flags of `ADD L, C`. But the half-carry flag might be temporarily set if there's a carry from L bit 3!

> 3. Which is right, that half-carry occurs from bit 7 to bit 8 or that half-carry occurs from bit 11 to bit 12 (in the case of 16-bit instructions)?

It depends on the instruction, but the flags are always updated based on the same bit positions if you think in terms of 8-bit values...it just varies whether we're talking about the high or low byte of the 16-bit value. Bit 11 is just bit 3 of the high byte.

- `ADD SP, e`: H from bit 3, C from bit 7 (flags from low byte op)
- `LD HL, SP+e`: H from bit 3, C from bit 7 (flags from low byte op)
- `ADD HL, rr`: H from bit 11, C from bit 15 (flags from high byte op)
- `INC rr`: no flag updates (executed by the 16-bit inc/dec unit)
- `DEC rr`: no flag updates (executed by the 16-bit inc/dec unit)

Comment: "Game Boy almost certainly has a 8-bit ALU" It has a 4-bit ALU

Comment: @GabrielOshiro Please supply any source to confirm this claim; I could only find some related to the Zilog Z80, none to the Sharp LR35902. Binary compatibility does not necessarily imply identical architecture; keep in mind that the trade-off between transistors and microcode gradually changed between 1976 and 1989.

Comment: Oh man, it's been a long time... but I used to study the reverse engineering of the z80 and the dmg CPU. I will look for the actual reference, but for now please consider my comment BS (or personal revelation)

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR: For `ADD SP,n`, the H-flag is set when carry occurs from bit 3 to bit 4.**

---

I decided to test this on real hardware, so I wrote a simple test ROM in GB-Z80 assembly that tests the following scenarios:

[SP = $000F]
`ADD SP,$01`

[SP = $00F0]
`ADD SP,$10`

[SP = $0FF0]
`ADD SP,$10`

For each case I store the value of register `F` after the `ADD` in memory, and I later display bit 5 (the H-flag) of each of those bytes on the screen.

I ran this on 3 different models (Gameboy Pocket, Gameboy Color, and Gameboy Advance SP), and got the following output on all 3 devices: `1 0 0`. So a carry from bit 3->4 caused H to be set, while a carry from 7->8 or 11->12 did not.

---

For `ADD HL,rr` (where `rr` is `BC/DE/HL/SP`) it appears to be a different story. Based on my testing, H is set if carry occurs from bit 11 to bit 12.

Comment: As a former professional GBC/DMG developer, I am impressed and horrified that you were able to answer this :)  But yes, bit's 3 to 4 are the answer as far as I remember as well, though I cannot remember ever using it.